# React Javascript Uncaught typeError undefined but defined for everything else?

Tags: reactjs, json, object

I am trying to figure out why does my console give me this "Uncaught TypeError" when everything else in the object seems to work?

Here's what I mean:

This is what I am getting from my data:

```
{ 
  "coord":{"lon":-117.8231,"lat":33.6695},
  "weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],
  "base":"stations",
  "main":{"temp":286.19,"feels_like":285.69,"temp_min":284.64,"temp_max":287.68,"pressure":1014,"humidity":82},
  "visibility":10000,
  "wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":160},
  "clouds":{"all":40},
  "dt":1676341708,
  "sys":{"type":1,"id":5876,"country":"US","sunrise":1676299070,"sunset":1676338403},
  "timezone":-28800,
  "id":5359777,
  "name":"Irvine",
  "cod":200
}
```

Now when I do `{console.log(weather)}` and `{console.log(weather['name'])}` it prints out the above on my console no problem

However, when I do `{console.log(weather['weather'][0]['main'])}` the app crashes and gives me the "Uncaught TypeError" error.

I did thought that maybe it could be that when my website loads (faster) than when we get the data from the API? but that wouldn't make sense since for `{console.log(weather)}` and `{console.log(weather['name'])}` work fine

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=someapikeyshere&q=irvine')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setWeather(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather)} //works fine
      {console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather['name'])} //works fine
      {console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather['weather'][0]['main])} //crashes
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `console.log` is imprecise when it comes to async data since output is updated; if you `JSON.stringify` the data you'll see what I mean. Your current code does not take into account whether or not the data has actually loaded (it should).

Answer (score 0):

> I did thought that maybe it could be that when my website loads (faster) than when we get the data from the API?

Indeed.  Because asynchronous operations are asynchronous.

The *initial value* for `weather` is `[]`:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
```

So when you do this:

```
console.log(weather)
```

It successfully logs an empty array.  And this:

```
console.log(weather['name'])
```

Successfully logs `undefined` or nothing at all.  And this:

```
console.log(weather['weather'][0]['main'])
```

Generates an error.  Because `weather['weather']` is `undefined`, which has no `0` index.

First thing's first... Should `weather` be an *array* or should it be an *object*?  Different parts of your code disagree on that.  Let's say it should be an object if that's the data your API returns.

In that case, don't initialize it to an empty array.  For the purposes of solving the problem, don't initialize it to anything at all:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState();
```

Then you can conditionally rely on `weather` being potentially `undefined` in your JSX.  For example:

```
<div className="App">
  {weather &&
    <>
    {console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather)}
    {console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather['name'])}
    {console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather['weather'][0]['main'])}
    </>
  }
</div>
```

Or perhaps:

```
<div className="App">
  {weather && console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather)}
  {weather && console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather['name'])}
  {weather && console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather['weather'][0]['main'])}
</div>
```

Etc.  How you structure it is up to you.  Overall the point is that, since your data isn't initially there, you need to test for it before trying to use it.

---

**Edit:** For added safety, if you're not sure of the structure of the object for example, you can also use optional chaining for all property access.  For example:

```
{console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather?.['weather']?.[0]?.['main'])}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your clear explaination! So i've tried the above solution and when I save my files it worked fine. However, when I refresh the page the console gave me the error "Uncaught TypeError: weather is undefined"

Comment: or even when I set it to ```useState({})``` it gave me the error ```weather.weather is undefine```

Comment: @SushiRiceOverEggs: Which specific line of code is producing that error?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates?  (Even off-site?)

Comment: the console says its at the line ```<div className="App">``` which I assume it meant the one below where I've called ```{console.log('This is in weather: ',  weather['weather'][0]['main])} ``` The above code is all there is to it except the API key from OpenWeather

Comment: @SushiRiceOverEggs: Have you made any changes suggested in this answer, or in any way conditionally confirmed that your object hierarchy exists before trying to use it?  The one line of code shown in that comment suggests not.  If `weather` is `undefined` or `{}` then trying to execute that exact `console.log` statement will produce an error, for the same reason it produced an error before posting the question above.  You can't read properties from `undefined` because it has no properties.

Comment: yes i've tried the above solution where I've set ```const [weather, setWeather] = useState();``` however, when I refreshed the page the console gave me the error ```Uncaught TypeError: weather is undefined```

Comment: This is really strange because when I use another API (news) and everything works fine

Comment: @SushiRiceOverEggs: Did you also make the suggested change to check if `weather` is `undefined` before using it?  The error suggests not.  Any way you structure it, you need to check if something exists before trying to use it.  There's no way around that.  That something could be the variable itself, it could be a property on the object, etc.

Comment: Yes I did. The error did went away however nothing shows up on the console anymore. Reason I need that data is because I need to populate my components

Comment: It's weird because this API is giving me this error however, another much simpler API (Array of objects) works whichever way i wanted it

Comment: @SushiRiceOverEggs: If the data isn't showing up then it's time for you to do some debugging.  When you do `console.log(weather)` when the component renders, what does it contain?  How does that differ from what you expect?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem (even if it's off-site)?